# How to save and retrieve files being downloaded by transmission bittorrent client?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I need to repair a computer of mine and I believe I'll need to reinstall all OS on it (Ubuntu/Haiku/Windows multiboot) but I would like to save for later retrieval some files in an on-going download procedure. Can it be done? I saved the magnetic links already, but I tried to restore one of the files being downloaded and I found no immediate way to store and retrieve it. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Different torrent clients will keep track of ongoing downloads in different ways. Transmission does its bookkeeping in files in `~/.config/transmission` in a binary format that is not intended for viewing.

However, files in a torrent that have not finished downloading will have a `.part` suffix attached to the file name. After the file has downloaded completely, the .part suffix is removed. Files that have not even started downloading will not be present.

Files with a proper name (i.e. without the `.part`) can therefore be safely copied elsewhere. Manually removing files before the download has finished will break the torrent though.

If you exit Transmission, copy the files that have been wholly or partly downloaded *and* the files in `~/.config/transmission` to a different system, I can see no reason why Transmission would not be able to simply resume downloading at the other location. (Exiting Transmission first is necessary to preserve integrity.) It wouldn't be much different from exiting and resuming Transmission on the same system.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed very enlightening. I was not aware of the binaries at '~/.config/transmission', chances are they can be copied and stored back later to the same directory so the ongoing '.part' files will be active again when the Transmission Client is started. Do you know if this would actually work? Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work, so I added this to my answer.

Comment: I'll try it and see how it goes. As I have any results I'll post them here. Thanks again!